# Wordpress custom link to wrap inserted images from media library

Tags: php, wordpress

I didn't expect this to be difficult but so far have failed at implementing it.

Simply I want to add a class name to the link tag that wraps the img tag when you insert an image into a post using the media library.

I want to turn this

```
<a href="http://..."><img src="http://..." alt="..." width="780" height="490" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-12" /></a>
```

Into this

```
<a href="http://..." class="fancylink fancybox.ajax"><img src="http://..." alt="..." width="780" height="490" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-12" /></a>
```

I can do it simply enough using jQuery, but I'd much prefer to use a wordpress filter or custom function. SO the output in the post includes the class name.

Comment: Try this http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11722/applying-automatic-link-class-to-images-embedded-to-posts

Answer (score 0):

Thanks msbodetti, the solution is as follows.

```
 function add_colorbox_class_to_image_links($html, $attachment_id, $attachment) {
    $linkptrn = "/<a[^>]*>/";
    $found = preg_match($linkptrn, $html, $a_elem);

    // If no link, do nothing
    if($found <= 0) return $html;

    $a_elem = $a_elem[0];

    // Check to see if the link is to an uploaded image
    $is_attachment_link = strstr($a_elem, "wp-content/uploads/");

    // If link is to external resource, do nothing
    if($is_attachment_link === FALSE) return $html;

    if(strstr($a_elem, "class=\"") !== FALSE){ 
        // If link already has class defined inject it to attribute
        $a_elem_new = str_replace("class=\"", "class=\"fancylink ", $a_elem);
        $html = str_replace($a_elem, $a_elem_new, $html);
    }else{ // If no class defined, just add class attribute
        $html = str_replace("<a ", "<a class=\"fancylink \" data-fancybox-group=\"gallery\" ", $html);
    }

    return $html;
}

add_filter('image_send_to_editor', 'add_colorbox_class_to_image_links', 10, 3);
```